# Allow ANY username to commit into SVN

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svn-server

To migrate from our old VCS, I want to permanently enable to commit into our repository with ANY username and no password prompted.
My script runs something like:

```
svn --username ANYNAME commit -m "testmsg" C:\path\to\file.txt
```

I need the server to accept any name that i enter for ANYNAME and it must not ask for a password, so that my script can keep committing.
Is that possible?

I use VisualSVN and my server runs on Http, not Https.

Please Help,

Thank you!

Comment: What's your task? It seems that you are taking a wrong turn 'ere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by editing the properties afterwards, so instead of committing with a fake username, which I can't make my server do, I do this :

```
svn propset --revprop -r HEAD svn:author NEW_AUTHOR_NAME
```

To make this work, you have to enable the "pre-revprop-change-hook" (example [here](http://public.procoders.net/pcsvm/hooks/pre-revprop-change.tmpl))

BEcause somebody asked - My task is to migrate the complete history of our Code , which was until now managed by a very outdated version control system ([QVCS](http://www.qumasoft.com/index1.html)),  to Subversion.
TO do this, i had to edit every user, because some of them aren't working here anymore and so i have to make my system to believe me ;)

Normally i wouldn't do this or even allow our server to accept such property changes, since editing and entering just any author-name is not the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

That will depend on how your svn server authentication is setup.
If you want to bypass authentication then you need to setup server accordingly, but its a very bad idea. How will you know who checked in the code?

Another approach can be, you can use a generic user for all svn work then you can hard-code username/password in a script.